# How multi-master ldap nodes handle concurrent update?

Tags: opendj

How multi master handle concurrent update to an element attribute?
Is it the last update win ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the last operation is "winning", the same way 2 independent applications would try to update the same attribute on the same server.